# How to achieve Robot framework Parallel test execution on two different machines?

Tags: java, selenium, robotframework, selenium-grid

I'm automating web application using RobotFramework with `selenium2library`.

I'm looking for parallel test execution of two different test suites on two different machines at the same time.

I tried pabot for parallel execution. If i am running 3 instances in parallel on a single machine it is running. But I want to run it in different machines, for that i have tried the below code:-

first I start hub

```
java -jar <selenium.jar> -role hub
```

(optional port f.e.: -port 4444)

Then I run up nodes:

```
java -jar <selenium.jar> -role webDriver (for selenium 2 library) -hub http://<selenium hub ip>:4444/grid/register
```

(optional parameter remoteHost f.e.: -remoteHost http://127.0.0.1:5555) 
Nodes can be run separately and be specified by additional parameter -remoteHost . This host can be used in selenium keyword Open Browser

Open Browser | url | browser=ff | alias=None | remote_url=False
Example:

```
${REMOTE_DRIVER}=    Set Variable    127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub   
Open Browser    www.google.com    ff    None    ${REMOTE_DRIVER}
```

But after this suits are running in different machines one after another and not in parallel.

Is there any way to acheive it.

Answer (score 1):

To run suites in parallel there are two components needed:

1. Selenium Grid, or other centralized Grid infra ([SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/), [Zalenium](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium), [Aerokube](https://github.com/aerokube) Selenoid).
2. Parallel Executor ([Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot))

Natively Robot Framework only supports running 1 suite at a time. By extension this means that any Robot script that uses Selenium will only have 1 suite running at a time. In order to parallelize you will need to run multiple Robot Framework instances in parallel.

The [Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot) project is a seperate application that runs a seperate robot framework instance per Suite (file). At the end it then merges all the seperate logs into a single log file. It has a few more features but that's the core.

From your description I take it that setting up a Grid where multiple nodes have joined succefully. If this is the case, then using the Grid server URL for connecting to your browser should suffice to have the nodes utilized.

Do make sure that the number of parallel Pabot processes (it's a parameter) do not exceed the number of available Selenium nodes.

Comment: Thanks ,yes I am able to connect the multiple node machines to the hub , but what is the exact command of pabot which will run multiple suites parallely. I tried the command given in the documentation for pabot but it seems it is not working.Can you please provide the copmmand